# Configure samba to allow all machines on the network full access to each other

Tags: samba

I have a LAN on which I run a number of Linux devices (a few Raspberry Pis, some Debian distros on old computers) and a few Windows devices. No one besides me uses this LAN.

The Linux machines are the problem when it comes to sharing folders. I've spent many hours  to find a way to edit `smb.conf` in such a way that every machine (different usernames) in my LAN can see all folders on every other machine, create files there, edit and remove stuff. Read, write, execute. Not some shared folder, all folders on all disks.

A few years ago I read an article by Joe Collins about this problem and used his code for `smb.conf`. This worked great, but I lost it.

Is there anyone who can provide me with the most irresponsible, dangerous block of code I can use in smb.conf?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us the details of your network, how it is set up, at least one smb.conf file that didn't work and how it failed, etc. We can't really help if we don't know what your setup is.

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: It should work for any Debian distro...

Comment: Bit confused. You surely mean all home directories, not all directories, right? You can only get access to all directories as root, and if you then really share all your files, including things like /proc and /sys, a simple in-file search might crash your system rather persistently.